# Is IIS performing an illegal character substitution? If so, how to stop it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, iis, unicode

Context: ASP.NET MVC running in IIS, with a a UTF-8 %-encoded URL.

Using the standard project template, and a test-action in `HomeController` like:

```
public ActionResult Test(string id)
{
    return Content(id, "text/plain");
}
```

This works fine for most %-encoded UTF-8 routes, such as:

```
http://mydevserver/Home/Test/%e4%ba%ac%e9%83%bd%e5%bc%81
```

with the expected result 京都弁

However using the route:

```
http://mydevserver/Home/Test/%ee%93%bb
```

the url is *not* received correctly.

Aside: `%ee%93%bb` is %-encoded code-point 0xE4FB; basic-multilingual-plane, private-use area; but ultimately - a valid unicode code-point; you can verify this manually, or via:

```
string value = ((char) 0xE4FB).ToString();
string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value); // %ee%93%bb
```

Now, what happens next depends on the web-server; on the Visual Studio Development Server (aka cassini), the correct `id` is received - a string of length one, containing code-point 0xE4FB.

If, however, I do this in IIS or IIS Express, I get a different `id`, specifically  `"î“»"`, code-points: 0xEE, 0x201C, 0xBB. You will immediately recognise the first and last as the start and end of our percent-encoded string... so what happened in the middle?

Well:

- code-point 0x93 is `“` ([source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0093/index.htm))
- code-point 0x201c is `“` ([source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201C/index.htm))

It looks to me very much like IIS has performed some kind of quote-translation when processing my url. Now maybe this might have uses in a few scenarios (I don't know), but it is certainly a bad thing when it happens in the middle of a %-encoded UTF-8 block.

Note that `HttpContext.Current.Request.Raw` **also** shows this translation has occurred, so this does not look like an MVC bug; note also Darin's comment, highlighting that it works differently in the path vs query portion of the url.

So (two-parter):

1. is my analysis missing some important subtlety of unicode / url processing?
2. how do I fix it? (i.e. make it so that I receive the expected character)

Comment: I don't know about IIS, but why do you think it should interpret the percent-encoding as using UTF-8?

Comment: I have no problem passing Unicode to my URL. Specifically λ. It gets encoded as `%CE%BB` - Unicode code point = `0x3BB`

Comment: @Joachim because that is how %-encoding works; it works correctly for most %-encoded unicode strings

Comment: I tested it on my site, it is not an IIS issue. http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=%EE%93%BB That simply dumps the content into the textbox on the site. When you click run, you will see on the network trace that the %EE%93%BB is correctly encoded/decoded.

Comment: @MarcGravell: As far as I know the relevant HTTP RFCs sadly *don't* specify which encoding to use for decoding percent-encoded parameters. That's a *constant* source of pain for developing in Java, unfortunately. Most browsers use the encoding used in the page from which the form is submitted, but that doesn't always help.

Comment: @leppie exactly; it works for **most** %-encoded unicode strings; `/Home/Test/0x3BB` returns (as expected) `λ` - it is just ***in the example given***, where this quote-substitution breaks things

Comment: @Joachim "and should convert all other characters to bytes according to UTF-8, and then percent-encode those values. This requirement was introduced in January 2005 with the publication of RFC 3986" ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding))

Comment: I don't know where fileformat.info got the left double quote glyph for U+0091. In Windows-1252 it is a left quote (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_1252#Codepage_layout)), but in [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/Code2Chart.pl) it is a control character – inherited from ISO 8559-1. Therefore I suspect this isn't a quote conversion, but somewhere something is re-encoding the URL into Windows-1252.

Comment: @leppie interesting; do you mind if I ask what your IronScheme one runs in? so I can understand where it breaks... for example, is that running any parts of ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC? or is it lower-level?

Comment: @MarcGravell: .NET 4 on that server, IIS integrated pipeline mode (full trust). Here is a proper example: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=(number-%3Estring+(char-%3Einteger+%23%5C%EE%93%BB)+16) All my stuff relies on the .NET encode/decode.

Comment: @MarcGravell: No MVC stuff though. Just a simple HTTPHandler.

Comment: @leppie interesting; I'll check a basic http-handler - good idea

Comment: @MarcGravell: Final attempt! http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=(number-%3Estring+(char-%3Einteger+%23%5C%EE%93%BB)+16)%0A

Comment: @leppie see edit; indeed, it works fine in a basic handler - maybe it is an MVC bug after all, then?

Comment: @MarcGravell: You sure it is not the routing module that is mismatching stuff?

Comment: @leppie if I already knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking the question ;p My "works in cassini but not IIS" may have led me to focus too much on IIS, but indeed - since a handler works OK, the routing module is looking highly suspicious now

Comment: That's definitely an IIS issue. It works in your handler because you are using a query string parameter. That works in ASP.NET MVC too. If you request `Home/Test?id=%ee%93%bb` you will get correct behavior in both Cassini and IIS. The generic handler doesn't work if you request it like this `My.ashx/%ee%93%bb` and then inspect the Request.RawUrl. The issues come from the fact that you are using unicode characters in the path of the url and not in the query string. I don't know why IIS behaves differently though on parsing the path portion of an URL.

Comment: Thanks @Darin - wow; crazy difference between the path/query!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Good call. I recall now the problems I had with the paths, and was why I moved over to the querystrings.

Comment: @leppi, that's exactly the reason why I use query string parameters for this kind of stuff as well.

Comment: I don't know how related it is, but a similar problem came up with a [simple plus (+) character between query and path]( http://serverfault.com/questions/76013/iis6-vs-iis7-and-iis7-5-handling-urls-with-plus-sign-in-base-not-querystr) .

Comment: @patridge thanks - that was a interesting; but unfortunately neither `@allowDoubleEscaping` nor `@allowHighBitCharacters` seems to make a difference here

Comment: Just in the spirit of checking the quote-translation thing, does it convert it to the other one (ending one) when you have two of them surrounding a word?

Comment: @Noon in the example given it is only one double-quote. Haven't test that.

Comment: Is Stack Exchange launching to other regions!? ... And sorry, don't know the answer :(

Comment: @William since you ask, this one came up from japanese.stackexchange.com, which *in English*, discusses usage etc of japanese.

Comment: Thanks, ok! Makes a lot of sense... Didn't realise just how much the network has grown.... not seen that site yet! (And cool - thanks for telling me about that site, never seen foreign characters in the address bar of Chrome... That is pretty cool!)... Hope you get a solution.

Comment: It looks like this is also directly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117342/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-actual-url-even-when-there-are-encoded-parts-in-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, to get around this, I had to use `request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"]` and some manual parsing, with a bunch of error-handling fallbacks (additionally compensating for some related glitches in `Uri`). Not great, but only affects a tiny minority of awkward requests.

Answer (score 9):

```
id = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(id));
```

This will give you your original id.
IIS uses Default (ANSI) encoding for path characters. Your url encoded string is decoded using that and that is why you're getting a weird thing back.

To get the original id you can convert it back to bytes and get the string using utf8 encoding.

See [Unicode and ISAPI Filters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/02/03/unicode-and-isapi-filters.aspx)

> ISAPI Filter is an ANSI API - all values you can get/set using the API
>   must be ANSI. Yes, I know this is shocking; after all, it is 2006 and
>   everything nowadays are in Unicode... but remember that this API
>   originated more than a decade ago when barely anything was 32bit, much
>   less Unicode. Also, remember that the HTTP protocol which ISAPI
>   directly manipulates is in ANSI and not Unicode.

*EDIT:* Since you mentioned that it works with most other characters so I'm assuming that IIS has some sort of encoding detection mechanism which is failing in this case. As a workaround though you can prefix your id with this char and then you can easily detect if the problem occurred (if this char is missing). Not a very ideal solution but it will work. You can then write your custom model binder and a wrapper class in ASP.NET MVC to make your consumption code cleaner.

Comment: Except that PU chars can't be made sense of in the default encoding.

Comment: Hmmm.... it doesn't fundamentally *fix* the problem, but that might be useful as an "eek" test (to detect whether the glitch *might* have happened). Most notably, it will corrupt anything that is **correctly** received. And in a more complex URL with both correctly and incorrectly received data, there is no real mechanism for knowing which are the "right" bits

Comment: @MarcGravell you can't fix it I guess. ASP.NET is a ISAPI filter. Path characters are used to find out which filter to invoke. Query string is processed by the filter itself thats why it works fine in query string.

Comment: I will, however, investigate a few of those server-variables (mentioned in the comments on that blog) (update: no use; they are all already munged by this point)

Comment: @Hasan in "integrated" mode, my understanding was that asp.net was *not* an ISAPI filter any more...?

Comment: @MarcGravell thats true. I would assume url path decoding is still an IIS function rather than ASP.NET runtime even in Integrated Mode.

Comment: @HasanKhan that still isn't an excuse to make a mess of it ;p

Comment: @Hasan a: because it gets it right for **virtually every example** - this non-working one really surprised us, and b: because under RFC3986 that is the correct way of interpreting it.

Comment: @Hasan additionally, `Accept-Charset` relates to the subsequent **response**, not the processing of the request.

Comment: @Hasan no, your snippet does not "always work" - try it with mixed content. The one character is just a misbehaving example. Real content is more like `what-are-the-main-differences-between-%E4%BA%AC%E9%83%BD%E5%BC%81kyoto-ben-and-%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%BC%81osaka-ben`

Answer (score 1):

Once Upon A Time, URLs themselves were not in UTF-8. They were in the ANSI code page. This facilitates the fact that they often are used to select, well, pathnames in the server's file system. In ancient times, IE had an option to tell whether you wanted to send UTF-8 URLs or not.

Perhaps buried in the bowels of the IIS config there is a place to specify the URL encoding, and perhaps not.

Comment: The thing is - it works correctly for **virtually all** urls; it is only this specific example that has a problem (and variants of it)

Comment: Do any of the other include characters outside the ISO-646 subset of Unicode? I don't see an indication in your question but I may not be reading closely enough.

Comment: indeed yes ;p for example `what-are-the-main-differences-between-京都弁kyoto-ben-and-大阪弁osaka-ben` workjs fine ;p (when UTF-8 / percent-encoded, etc) [link](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/367/what-are-the-main-differences-between-%E4%BA%AC%E9%83%BD%E5%BC%81kyoto-ben-and-%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%BC%81osaka-ben)

Comment: Hmm. OK, that does cast some pretty good doubt on us answerers' beliefs here. It's been so long ...