# URL in MVC significance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Summary(int claimId,bool status)
```

and I have  hyper links to  this.

```
1.http://localhost:2020/Coverage/Summary/60/true
2.http://localhost:2020/Coverage/Summary?claimId=60&status==true
```

both the above link will work for me.

in mvc i think we need to follow the first way.

What is the significance of this type of URL.
Does this type of URL have any connection with REST?

Answer (score 1):

Both URL formats would be considered REST because all data necessary to render the view is passed to the server as parameters. In today's REST world, the first URL format would be consider a 'clean' URL because it doesn't use request parameters directly, but effectively they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> in mvc i think we need to follow the first way.

Not necessary.

> What is the significance of this type of URL

Mainly visual and in some cases might be easier for the user to remember as it is shorter. Be careful though as you might get into [serious troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913830/is-iis-performing-an-illegal-character-substitution-if-so-how-to-stop-it) if you start putting all parameters as url path tokens. So use with moderation. Would work fine with integer values where you have control over but if you start using this for every query string parameter even those entered by users you might encounter problems.

Moreover, since the order of parameters is now important as they no longer have names, if some of them are optional, the routing can no longer disambiguate between them.

> Does this type of URL have any connection with REST?

No.

Answer (score 0):

The first way (path-based) only makes sense if the path identifies the resource being shown.  [That is the central principle of RESTful URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Central_principle).  So unique items like "Id" make sense in the path.

However, options should be displayed as query strings.  The query string contains both a `key` and a `value`, which gives them more meaning but less significance than path-based URLs.

The default MVC Routing puts all "id" values in the path, and all others in the query-string.  So I usually follow that route.  In your case, I'd definitely recommend #2, because `claimId` and `status` do not seem to identify `Summary`.