# url decoding in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-4.0, urldecode, encodeuricomponent

I have a form in asp.net with a few textboxes. I'm trying to post the values in them to the server using jquery ajax, but having problems. I'm using javascript encodeURIComponent for the values of the textboxes, and then posting, but I see that the url is encoded automatically:

```
wanted result:
mylefturl/first%20name/last%20name

this is what's actually happenning:
mylefturl/first name/last name
```

and so I get an asp.net error ...

my javascript code:

```
var firstName = $("#SignupFirstName").val();
            var lastName = $("#SignupLastName").val();
            var email = $("#SignupEmail").val();
            var password = $("#SignupPassword").val();

            var url = '/Ajax/GetSignup/' + encodeURIComponent(firstName) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(lastName) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(email) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(password);
$.ajax({
                    url: u,
...
```

What is the solution to this ?

Comment: Everything seems fine. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDuza/) is an example. There might be another error. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: the problem actually comes up when I try to call the encoded url in asp.net, and so it seems like it's decoding it automatically, turning it to the example above:  mylefturl/first[space]name/last[space]name, does asp.net have a decoding mechanism for urls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the `data` parameter when sending the AJAX call:

```
var firstName = $("#SignupFirstName").val(),
    lastName = $("#SignupLastName").val(),
    email = $("#SignupEmail").val(),
    password = $("#SignupPassword").val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/GetSignup/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        firstName: firstName, 
        lastName: lastName, 
        email: email, 
        password: password 
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // TODO: process the results from the AJAX call
    }
});
```

Now jQuery will take care of properly url encoding the values sent to the server. Those values will be sent as part of the POST payload instead of the url. It's the safest way to ensure that they get correctly to the server. I would recommend you to avoid using user entered values as part of your url path. Take a look at the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913830/is-iis-performing-an-illegal-character-substitution-if-so-how-to-stop-it) to understand what difficulties you might face if you ever go that route.