# How can I reliably get the actual URL, even when there are percent-encoded parts in the path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

IIS and ASP.NET (MVC) [has some glitches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913830/is-iis-performing-an-illegal-character-substitution-if-so-how-to-stop-it) when working with urls with %-encoding in the *path* (not the query-string; the query-string is fine). How can I get around this? i.e. how can I get the actual URL that was requested?

For example, if I navigate to `/x%3Fa%3Db` and (separately) to `/x?a=b` - both of them report the `.Request.Url` as `/x?a=b` - because the encoded data *in the path* is reported incorrectly.

Comment: While the thought is appreciated, StackOverflow is *not* a snippet site or a place to post things you figure out, i.e. a blog. The timestamps of your question and answer indicate that you came here ready to post both. Please only post questions you truly need help with. There are more appropriate ways to just share information with the community.

Comment: @Chris [Self answering has always been acceptable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). The decision to allow answering *as part of asking* was also taken very deliberately - that code was added very intentionally. I know: I work on that team. Furthermore, this code has been shared as part of a request by a user on "meta" after I fixed a [stackoverflow bug caused by this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169356). Tl;Dr: answering your own question is explicitly OK, as long as the question and answer are well formed and appropriate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way I've tacked this is to look at the underlying server-variables; the `URL` variable contains a *decoded* value; the `QUERY_STRING` variable contains the still-encoded query.  We can't just call *encode* on the `URL` part, because that also contains the orignal `/` etc in their original form - if we blindly encode the entire thing we'll get unwanted `%2f` values; however, can pull it apart and spot problematic cases:

```
private static readonly Regex simpleUrlPath = new Regex("^[-a-zA-Z0-9_/]*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static readonly char[] segmentsSplitChars = { '/' };
// ^^^ avoids lots of gen-0 arrays being created when calling .Split
public static Uri GetRealUrl(this HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    var baseUri = request.Url; // use this primarily to avoid needing to process the protocol / authority
    try
    {
        var vars = request.ServerVariables;
        var url = vars["URL"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) || simpleUrlPath.IsMatch(url)) return baseUri; // nothing to do - looks simple enough even for IIS

        var query = vars["QUERY_STRING"];
        // here's the thing: url contains *decoded* values; query contains *encoded* values

        // loop over the segments, encoding each separately
        var sb = new StringBuilder(url.Length * 2); // allow double to be pessimistic; we already expect trouble
        var segments = url.Split(segmentsSplitChars);
        foreach (var segment in segments)
        {
            if (segment.Length == 0)
            {
                if(sb.Length != 0) sb.Append('/');
            }
            else if (simpleUrlPath.IsMatch(segment))
            {
                sb.Append('/').Append(segment);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append('/').Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(segment));
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) sb.Append('?').Append(query); // query is fine; nothing needing
        return new Uri(baseUri, sb.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { // if something unexpected happens, default to the broken ASP.NET handling
        GlobalApplication.LogException(ex);
        return baseUri;
    }
}
```